# How to do a image search on my server-side database from ios app?

Tags: ios, opencv

I am trying to develop an ios app using Objective C.I aim to capture an image through the camera and perform an image recognition against the collection of images on the server-side database.

How should I proceed with the development? Can any one suggest me open source sdk or tool or method to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You must call API and send imageName Key to the server.

And use `SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '%image_name%';` on your server side. this sql query send that all data which contain that keyword .

Comment: Thank you Bijendra. But this is what I am not looking for. I need suggestion on what sdks need to be used for image recognition.